# delete last item in all rows and columns numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, del

I am trying to delete the last item in both the rows and columns in my `numpy.ndarray` (`type = class numpy.ndarray`). My array has 30 rows and 180 columns (i.e. 180 values per row). I have tried `numpy.delete` but this simply removes the whole row/column.

To illustrate what I want to achieve I created the following example in Python using and array and nested for loops:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]],[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]])
for list in a:
    for sublist in list:
        del sublist[-1]
```

Using

```
print(a)
```

Gives the following array:

> ```
> [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
> ```

Using

```
print(list)
```

after the for loops gives:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Unfortunately using this on my array gives the following error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item deletion

Thanks

---

**Update:**
I am extracting my information from a grid NetCDF file. I have changed the word `list` to `l` since `list` is a Python keyword. This didn't change it for me.

This provides a good example of my array:

```
c = np.arange(5400).reshape(30,180)
for l in c:
    for i in l:
        del i[-1]
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    del i[-1] 
 TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item deletion
```

Comment: its worked for me. Do not use keyword as variable name. `list` is keyword of Python

Comment: For a ragged array, how could you have rows and columns?

Comment: @VivekSable See Update in main post

Comment: In the example in the update, you can "delete" last column and last row with `c = c[:-1, :-1]`. I don't understand what you want in the other example with the array of dtype `object`, though.

Comment: In your second example, your array has a shape (30,180). When looping twice through it you end up with a int, not with an array. So calling del i[-1] is not gonna work.

Comment: I agree with Michael, using slicing is the best way to do what you want to achieve. Nested for loops are significantly slower.

Comment: @Michael I think slicing gives me the desired output. I will test it with my values, plot them and get back to you.

Comment: @Ben thank you. Now that you put it this way, indeed looping over it twice, I will end up with an integer and not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del i[-1]` is a list operation.  `np.array` does not support that.

[Count the occurrences of a specific value and remove them at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371426/count-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-value-and-remove-them-at-the-same-time) demonstrates the differences between lists and arrays when it comes to deletion.

Your example `a` is object dtype, containing lists

```
In [111]: a.shape
Out[111]: (11,)
In [112]: [len(i) for i in a]
Out[112]: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
In [113]: a[0]
Out[113]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

`a[0]` is a 3 element list, with sublists of different length.

It's not clear what you want to delete.  Delete elements from `a`, or elements from each element of `a`, or elements from the sublists of those elements.

Furthermore, if the real data is from `NetCDF` it might actually a multidimensional array.  Or if object dtype, the elements might themselves be (2d) arrays.

In case, slicing is the right way to remove rows/columns from an array:

```
In [114]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [115]: a
Out[115]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [116]: a[:-1, :-1]
Out[116]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

The result is a `view`; it does not change `a` itself.  `a = a[:-1, :-1].copy()` is the cleanest way to creates a reduced size array without leaving the any of the original around.