# delete the last element in the array with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

i have problem like this..

```
arr = [['1' '2' '']['3' '4' '']['5' '6' '']]
```

then, how do I delete the last element - array[n][2]
I have tried and searching google a lot but didn't solve it
please help me to solve this problem thank you...

```
arr = [['1' '2']['3' '4']['5' '6']]
```

Comment: Please format the array  correctly! Also show what you have tried in terms of code!

Comment: Do you want to remove the last one or empty one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete last item in all rows and columns numpy.ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371757/delete-last-item-in-all-rows-and-columns-numpy-ndarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy.delete(arr,-1,1)

```
arr = numpy.array([['1','2',''],['3','4',''],['5','6','']])
arr = numpy.delete(arr,-1,1)
```

The result will be:

```
[['1' '2']
['3' '4']
['5' '6']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) to remove the last element from each sublist

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([['1', '2', ''],['3' ,'4', ''],['5', '6' ,'']])

#Slice each sublist to remove the last element using apply_along_axis
arr = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[:-1], 1, arr)
print(arr)
```

The output will be

```
[['1' '2']
 ['3' '4']
 ['5' '6']]
```

Comment: Hold on. There is a `numpy` tag.

Comment: Even if it was a numpy array, map will still work @Austin, I updated my answer to reflect that! I didn't understand the reason of downvote though?

Comment: I agree it works, but OP is asking for numpy way to solve it.

Comment: Sure thing @Austin , I used a numpy function for it, please check and if it looks good, please consider upvoting :)

Comment: @Austin But, There is no array with numpy in their code. `arr` is just `list`.   I think `numpy` is not mandatory if we can solve it in standard library.

Comment: @yahocho, mandatorily no, but when OP asks we should be answering accordingly. And what OP shown is not code but a representation, originally it might be a numpy array.

Comment: If you are going to iterate on the rows, this would be simpler: `np.array([x[:-1] for x in arr])`.  `np.apply_along_axis` makes for prettier iteration when dealing with 3d or larger arrays, but is overkill in 2d.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [415]: arr = np.array([['1', '2', ''],['3' ,'4', ''],['5', '6' ,'']]) 
     ...:                                                                            
In [416]: arr                                                                        
Out[416]: 
array([['1', '2', ''],
       ['3', '4', ''],
       ['5', '6', '']], dtype='<U1')
```

Just take a column slice:

```
In [417]: arr[:, :-1]                                                                
Out[417]: 
array([['1', '2'],
       ['3', '4'],
       ['5', '6']], dtype='<U1')
```

This produces a new array, but that's normal with `numpy`.  Most `numpy` actions, especially ones that change size/shape, do that.

The OP display of `arr` is consistent with it being `numpy` array.  However for copy-n-paste the `repr` display is better.

```
In [418]: print(arr)                                                                 
[['1' '2' '']
 ['3' '4' '']
 ['5' '6' '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to check '' with len().

```
arr = [['1', '2', ''],['3', '4', ''],['5', '6', '']]
arr = [[a for a in ar if len(a) > 0] for ar in arr]
print (arr)
```

The result is:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```